# Getting warning "Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated"

Tags: php

I am getting this warning:

> Deprecated: Function `ereg()` is deprecated in

PHP Code:

```
if ($kill_bullets == 0 || !$kill_bullets || ereg('[^0-9]',$kill_bullets)){
    echo "Invalid Bullets!";
} elseif ($kill_bullets != 0 || $kill_bullets || !ereg('[^0-9]',$kill_bullets)) {
}
```

Comment: Use **[`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)** instead.

Comment: CertaiN could you post what it should look like please

Comment: @user3808505: just look at the doc pages for the link CertaiN gave you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!$kill_bullets || !ctype_digit($kill_bullets)) {
    echo "Invalid Bullets!";
}
```

---

> When i click sumbit button nothing happens?

Try this snippet.

```
if (!$kill_bullets || !ctype_digit($kill_bullets)) {
    echo "Invalid Bullets!";
} else {
    echo "Valid Bullets. okay.";
}
```

Comment: When i click sumbit button nothing happens?

Comment: Are you using `$_POST` or `$_GET`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: Does your `<form>` have attribute `method="post"` ?

Comment: Are you accessing via `http://` or `https://` protocol? `file://` is invalid for PHP.

Comment: I am accessing via http://

Comment: Updated post. Try that snippet.

Comment: I missed abit of the php code sorry. I have updated it that could of been the problem

Comment: Don't you have mistake in conditions with `elseif`? I think `||` should be `&&`. Then... Why are you using `elseif` with contrary conditions? Just use `else`.

Comment: if ($kill_bullets == 0 || !$kill_bullets || ereg('[^0-9]',$kill_bullets)){
    echo "Invalid Bullets!";
} else ($kill_bullets != 0 || $kill_bullets || !ereg('[^0-9]',$kill_bullets)) {
}

You mean like that?

Comment: `if ($kill_bullets == 0 || !$kill_bullets || ereg('[^0-9]',$kill_bullets)) { echo "Invalid Bullets!"; } else { }`

Comment: Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in still showing

Comment: if (!$kill_bullets || !ctype_digit($kill_bullets)) {
    echo "Invalid Bullets!";
} else {
    echo "Valid Bullets. okay.";
}

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX compatible regexps [are deprecated](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/intro.regex.php). You should use the PCRE instead.

[preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) would be the equivalent to ereg with a little bit different syntax.